# Unexpected result for autolayout on iphone 6 plus

Tags: ios, autolayout, iphone-6-plus

I've added a uiview on a view controller(VC), trying to set it's width is equals to VC's view's width.

What I set and expected:
[image: xcode setting and expected result]

And what i got on iphone 6 plus:
[image: what i got on ip6+]

I've tried to change the constants of leading space and trailing space and no help.
Is there any special for iphone 6+ autolayout?

The view setting here is "Any width x Regular height"

-------Added Dec 2016
To people who is confused by this case like me:
There is a [layout margin](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622566-layoutmargins) property in UIView, which is an UIEdgeInsets(8,8,8,8). It is something like css padding.

> When the edge of your view is close to the edge of the superview and the preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins property is true, the actual layout margins may be increased to prevent content from overlapping the superview’s margins.
>
> The default margins are eight points on each side.
>
> If the view is a view controller’s root view, the system sets and
>   manages the margins. The top and bottom margins are set to zero
>   points. The side margins vary depending on the current size class, but
>   can be either 16 or 20 points. You cannot change these margins.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try to remove the check Constrain to margins when adding constraints. Here take a look:

Constrain to margins is checked and its result

[image: Constrain to margins] [image: result]

Now, after removing the constraints and re-adding the constraints with Constrain to margins unchecked, here is the result:

[image: Constrain to margins unchecked] [image: result without Constrain to margins]

Comment: I also suffer from this couple times. Looks like a xcode bug?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a bug, most likely iphone 6 plus have higher margins than other iphones.

Comment: Is there any Apple docs/resource that explains how they calculate margins on each device?

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo No, there is no document that explains how they calculate margins of the devices. Even no cheat sheets have any details on this.

Comment: @SharonNathaniel Damn, that is very confusing. I still don't get why there's a margin on iPhone 6 Plus, but not anything else. Thanks anyway for the answer. Cheers.

Comment: @SharonNathaniel when I uncheck that box it is getting rechecked Automatically. Any ideas why it might be happening??

Comment: @Priyatham51 For every view you will have to uncheck it .. depending upon your requirement.

Answer (score 19):

Sharon's answer works wonderfully, but you don't have to delete the existing constraints to solve the problem. You may edit existing constraints removing the extraneous margin:

[image: Before applying solution]
[image: Solution step]
[image: After applying solution]

Comment: I'm having this same probem. How did you add Horizontal Space Constraint?

Comment: Are you familiar with creating autolayout constraints? It's just a matter of creating a regular constraint and unchecking the "Relative to margin" option.

Comment: @4thSpace : when you uncheck the margin, it will automatically change from a Leading constraint to a Horizontal Constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Editing existing constraints to remove the extraneous margin will not work. You have to delete the existing constraints and add new ones keeping constraints to margin unselected.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue for my "Done" button. The issue was my View (Done Button) was in base View hierarchy so i bring view back in root view (view controller's view). and set constraints accordingly.

My case set constraints Pin-> Uncheck Constraints to Margin -> Bottom,Leading,Trailing (Constraints value=0)

[image]

Make sure view hierarchy should not be following way.(Subview might be but cut view must not).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I had this bug in the iPhone 6 plus simulator. But in the 6 plus device this bug didn't happen. This could be just a bug with 6 plus simulators.